# In Octave, how do I specify that the solution to a matrix equation should be over integers?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, octave, mixed-integer-programming

In Octave, how do I specify that the solution to a matrix equation should be over integers?
I.e., Given matrix $A$, vectors $x$ and $b$; $Ax=b$. Find vector $x=A^{-1}b$ such that all its entries are integers. While I'm primarily concerned with Octave, your answer may alternatively consider Wolfram|Alpha, or any other software available with a free online interface. If discussing Wolfram|Alpha or other systems, please also explain how to load a sparse matrix, which is currently in row, col, value format (i.e., I would prefer to do minimal format conversions).

$A$, in sparse format (row, col, value):

```
1 1 1
2 1 1
3 2 1
4 3 1
5 3 1
6 4 1
7 4 1
8 4 1
9 5 1
10 5 1
11 6 1
12 6 1
13 7 1
14 9 1
15 9 1
16 10 1
17 11 1
18 12 1
19 12 1
20 13 1
21 13 1
22 14 1
23 14 1
24 14 1
25 15 1
26 15 1
27 16 1
28 17 1
29 17 1
30 17 1
31 18 1
32 19 1
33 20 1
34 20 1
```

Coefficients:

```
30
27
26
26
24
25
25
20
17
21
13
14
17
18
17
13
14
13
12
12
11
6
2
3
3
2
4
2
3
0
2
1
4
4
```

Comment: What about your system guarantees that the entries $x$ are integers?

Comment: It's a requirement I imposed upon the solution. Even if no such solution exists I still need to only consider the integers.

Comment: If no solution exists in the integers, it should just return "no solution" (as opposed to some integer $x$ that is as close as possible to the solution)?

Comment: Yes, because I know there is a solution in the reals.

Comment: What I wanted to clarify was whether you wanted the vector of integers which minimized the residual, or just the actual solution if the entries are integers and "no solution" otherwise.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear how there can be residual error if the vector is composed of integers, but I was only looking for integers, not approximate results. I'm going to include the matrix and coefficients in the question, so that you can try it out yourself (if you want to) and post the resulting vector if it works.

Comment: What's the application domain of this problem?  In other words, what's your scientific goal here?

Comment: I would tell you, but I'd rather not because I'm exploring a problem and I'd like to analyze it on my own, even if it proves inefficient. I hope you understand.

Comment: Your first two rows give $x_1=30$ and $x_1=27$ at the same time, which is impossible. Such conflicting assignments continue multiple times.

Answer (score 7):

If $A$ is full-rank, there is only one solution to $Ax=b$, and it is either integer or not.

If $A$ is not full-rank, this problem starts to look like a search for least common multiples in the null space or integer programming.

This isn't something that a general numerical linear algebra solver like those in Octave will be able to do on its own.  If your problem is large, you could try entering this as a feasibility problem into an integer programming solver like [lpsolve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.1/Octave.htm) or [COIN-CBC](https://projects.coin-or.org/Cbc).  If $A$ is not so big or nearly full-rank, then you might try an eigenvalue decomposition and searching in the null space for the nearest set of integers.